# Help with Workflow for updating field

Tags: workflow

I have two fields:

1. Area (Text field)
2. Pricebook (Picklist field) both are on account.

My requirement is to create a workflow in which if pricebook field is there so area also get update with it.

But is it possible if my pricebook value is : "21 SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA" so area only update "21" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign below formula in **Specify New Field Value** section of **Account.Area__c** workflow field update.

```
LEFT( Account.Pricebook__c , FIND(" ", Account.Pricebook__c))
```

in above formula, **FIND** function which returns the length of the characters until 'Space' is found. and then use **LEFT** function to Returns the specified number of characters from the beginning of a text string.

For more information check out [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/customize_functions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Use formula field update to extract first two characters, so formula could be

```
Left(Text(Pricebook__c),FIND(" ",Text(Pricebook__c)) - 1 )
```

note it will find first ' '(space) and extract all characters before that, so need to add picklist values carefully. and expected are value must occur before first ' '(space)